# What type of motor is this?

Tags: motor, hardware, diy

So I recently bought a motorised pedicure set thinking it would be some amazing thing. However, I used it once and the batteries (4 AA) died after about half an hour and not before getting ridiculously hot.

I decided I would take it apart to see what mad electronics have gone into it, and it turns out it is literally just a button and then wired straight into the motor. So I have decided I would like to replace the motor with one that has a higher torque (was really not very powerful so didn't have much effect) as well as possibly a higher RPM.

After taking it apart and finding the motor, I tried to find out what type of motor it currently is but it has no markings or part numbers on it at all so I couldn't find out. I wanted to know this so I could know the characteristics of it and things like that so I know how to get a better motor that would provide a better product!

Here are some pictures of the motor in various stages of assembly and I was wondering if anyone could help out with regards to what type of motor it is, and if anyone has any comments/solutions to some of the issues I mentioned they would also be greatly welcomed!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As it might not be clear from the pictures, inside the 'drum' of the motor are two magnets that the coiled wire sits in.

I have taken the voltage and current readings of it and it is as follows:
**Voltage:** Anywhere between 4V - 12V it seems to work, towards 12V it starts going a little bit mental.
**Current:** Around 500 - 600mA.

Comment: Carbon brushes?

Comment: It is an ordinary brushed DC motor. To find a suitable replacement, you need at least to measure its operating voltage. RC hobby shops will almost certainly have something similar and more powerful than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an ordinary brushed DC permanent-magnet motor.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [DC motor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_motor), like those used in radio-controlled toys or models. This in particular is a permanent magnet motor. You should try to determine the supply voltage.

**Append**: For a 6V DC motor, maybe [this](http://www.sourcingmap.com/6v-4000rpm-002a-mini-dc-motor-for-smart-cars-diy-toys-p-135491.html) is a good reference.

Comment: It's running off of 4 AA batteries so it must be rated for 6 volts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a motor with higher torque.  The torque is low on purpose.
If it had higher torque, you could grind right through a finger nail or the tip of your finger - ouch.  Even a buffing wheel could rub hard enough to get painfully hot.

If the motor is really horrible (real cheap trash) then you might need a better motor - but then I'd suggest a current limiter to keep the torque down.